# Navigate on web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have three pages Parent page, Detail list page and Detail edit page. When I navigate to Detail list page from Parent page I also pass returnUrl parameter and I'm getting url like this (http://localhost:52243/Contract/List?returnUrl=/Customer/id?d08d4f10-f7c7-492c-814b-81f7b3971cd1). Then I do post request and have redirect Detail edit page. There I have link via I go back to (http://localhost:52243/Contract/List?returnUrl=/Customer/id?d08d4f10-f7c7-492c-814b-81f7b3971cd1). And now when I try click back button I need open (http://localhost:52243/Customer/id?d08d4f10-f7c7-492c-814b-81f7b3971cd1) instead Detail edit page url.

Comment: Could you add more information ? We can't help without more informations of what you are trying to achieve, what did you try, where are you stuck etc...